# Using jWYSIWYG to output BBCode

Tags: php, jquery, wysiwyg, bbcode, jwysiwyg

I really like jWYSIWYG - it's simple, and it works with jQuery. I also understand it's pretty customizable and a good ground base for custom needs -- but the documentation is lacking. I wanna know how I can use it to output simple BBCode, and how I can create my own custom buttons. A simple example should do the trick, I don't need heavy explanation... I know my way bit around coding, I just need to find the right approach to this.

Answer (score 2):

[markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) is a jQuery plugin that provides what you are looking for. It's not a WYSIWYG editor, but pretty much closer to that - more like this editor (StackOverflow's). Here is an example that shows [BBCode editor](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/bbcode/).

Here are a few BBCode editors that do provide WYSIWYG,

- http://wysiwygbbcode.codeplex.com/
- http://www.ecardmax.com/hoteditor/

Comment: How easily can I add a new set of BBCodes to it?

Comment: All you've to do is to add it to you BBCode configuration JSON. Have a look at the JSON in the BBcode example in my answer.

Comment: Alright sweet. I'll keep this question open for now since it doesn't actually have WYSIWYG, but I like the simplicity in this and it's a good solution for now. Thanks :)